# RuntimeError: Cannot find callable custom in hubconf

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, torchvision

```
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import torch
----> 3 model = torch.hub.load('C:/Users/user/Desktop/***/model/', 'custom', path='runs/train/***/weights/best.pt', force_reload = True, source='local')
      4 # Images
      5 imgs = ['/kaggle/input/***/images/image-1.png']  # batch of images

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py:404, in load(repo_or_dir, model, source, force_reload, verbose, skip_validation, *args, **kwargs)
    401 if source == 'github':
    402     repo_or_dir = _get_cache_or_reload(repo_or_dir, force_reload, verbose, skip_validation)
--> 404 model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
    405 return model

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py:432, in _load_local(hubconf_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
    429 hubconf_path = os.path.join(hubconf_dir, MODULE_HUBCONF)
    430 hub_module = _import_module(MODULE_HUBCONF, hubconf_path)
--> 432 entry = _load_entry_from_hubconf(hub_module, model)
    433 model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
    435 sys.path.remove(hubconf_dir)

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py:240, in _load_entry_from_hubconf(m, model)
    237 func = _load_attr_from_module(m, model)
    239 if func is None or not callable(func):
--> 240     raise RuntimeError('Cannot find callable {} in hubconf'.format(model))
    242 return func

RuntimeError: Cannot find callable custom in hubconf
```

I use pytorch on my project
I would use saved model which on wandb by using torch.hub.load()
But there is some entry point error, It's not work
I have read related documents and discussions, but I couldn't find a solution.

**please help.....**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.